# presentModalViewController resulting in mysterious zombie

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an curious zombie bug that seems to have crept out of the woodwork in a longstanding app.  I like to think I know what I'm doing, and zombies are normally straight-forward to fix, but this one has me puzzled.

Instruments reports that the zombie object is a view that I'm presenting as a modal view (MyPopUpViewController).  Here's the code that presents the modal view controller.

```
MyPopUpViewController *popUpViewController =
                    [[MyPopUpViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController =
                    [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popUpViewController];

[popUpViewController release];

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES]; // zombie occurs here

                [navigationController release];
```

Within MyPopUpViewConroller, when the user taps 'Done' on the navigation bar, the modal view controller is dismissed - standard stuff, and works 99 out of 100 times (or more).

However, if I'm quick getting in and out of the modal dialog, and only on the simulator (that I've seen), I get the zombie reported below.

Now, I believe that if I push MyPopUpViewController to the navigation controller, it will be retained by the navigation controller, so I'm safe to release it.  Likewise, the tabBarController will retain the navigation controller, so I'm safe to release that too, as shown in the code.

From the Instruments diagnostics, these are my only retain / releases of MyPopUpViewController (see references to 'myapp' in the 'Responsible' column), and it's the iOS internals that later [apparently?] cause the zombie.

I'd appreciate suggestions as to why I'm seeing this zombie. Thanks.

```
#   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Malloc  1   00:10.669.925   176 myapp   -[MyPopUpViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
1   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  2   00:10.670.707   0   UIKit   -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:]
2   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  3   00:10.670.721   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
3   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.670.723   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
4   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 2   00:10.671.467   0   myapp   -[MyPopUpViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
5   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  3   00:10.671.494   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
6   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.671.496   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
7   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  4   00:10.671.497   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
8   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.671.497   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
9   0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  5   00:10.672.129   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
10  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.130   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
11  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  6   00:10.672.131   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
12  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.132   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
13  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  7   00:10.672.138   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
14  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.139   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
15  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  8   00:10.672.140   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
16  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.141   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
17  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  9   00:10.672.489   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
18  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.490   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
19  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  10  00:10.672.491   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
20  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.492   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
21  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  11  00:10.672.796   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
22  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.797   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
23  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  12  00:10.672.801   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
24  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.802   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
25  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  13  00:10.672.804   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
26  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.804   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
27  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  14  00:10.672.829   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
28  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.830   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
29  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  15  00:10.672.830   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
30  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.672.832   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
31  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  16  00:10.686.674   0   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
32  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  17  00:10.686.696   0   UIKit   +[UIProxyObject addMappingFromIdentifier:toObject:forCoder:]
33  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  18  00:10.687.241   0   UIKit   -[UIProxyObject initWithCoder:]
34  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  19  00:10.687.244   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
35  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  20  00:10.687.254   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
36  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  21  00:10.687.261   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
37  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  22  00:10.687.270   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
38  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  23  00:10.689.785   0   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
39  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  24  00:10.689.806   0   UIKit   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
40  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 23  00:10.690.037   0   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
41  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 22  00:10.690.056   0   UIKit   +[UIProxyObject removeMappingsForCoder:]
42  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 21  00:10.690.086   0   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
43  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 20  00:10.690.117   0   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
44  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 19  00:10.690.124   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
45  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 18  00:10.690.134   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
46  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 17  00:10.690.155   0   UIKit   -[UINibDecoder finishDecoding]
47  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 16  00:10.690.166   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
48  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 15  00:10.690.174   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
49  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  16  00:10.690.494   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
50  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.690.497   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
51  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  17  00:10.690.510   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
52  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.690.511   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
53  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  18  00:10.690.521   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
54  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.690.522   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
55  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  19  00:10.695.693   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
56  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.695.693   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
57  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  20  00:10.695.704   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
58  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 19  00:10.695.721   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:]
59  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  20  00:10.701.163   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
60  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.701.164   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
61  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  21  00:10.701.212   0   UIKit   -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
62  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 20  00:10.701.235   0   UIKit   -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
63  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  21  00:10.701.302   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
64  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.701.302   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
65  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  22  00:10.701.304   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
66  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.701.304   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
67  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  23  00:10.701.342   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
68  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 22  00:10.701.356   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
69  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  23  00:10.701.386   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
70  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.701.387   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
71  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  24  00:10.701.399   0   UIKit   -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
72  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 23  00:10.701.414   0   UIKit   -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
73  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 22  00:10.701.762   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
74  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 21  00:10.701.774   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
75  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 20  00:10.701.775   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
76  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 19  00:10.701.809   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
77  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 18  00:10.701.821   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
78  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 17  00:10.701.943   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
79  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 16  00:10.701.945   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
80  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 15  00:10.701.947   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
81  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 14  00:10.701.985   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
82  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 13  00:10.701.985   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
83  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 12  00:10.701.989   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
84  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 11  00:10.701.989   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
85  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 10  00:10.701.990   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
86  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 9   00:10.702.017   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
87  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 8   00:10.702.018   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
88  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 7   00:10.702.039   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
89  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 6   00:10.702.040   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
90  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 5   00:10.702.041   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
91  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 4   00:10.702.042   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
92  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 3   00:10.702.051   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
93  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 2   00:10.702.052   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
94  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 1   00:10.702.096   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
95  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  2   00:10.702.195   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
96  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:10.702.196   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
97  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 1   00:10.709.439   0   QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
98  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  2   00:11.110.856   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
99  0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:11.110.856   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
100 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  3   00:11.110.858   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
101 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:11.110.859   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
102 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  4   00:11.110.924   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
103 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:11.110.925   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
104 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 3   00:11.111.052   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
105 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 2   00:11.111.053   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
106 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 1   00:11.111.054   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
107 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  2   00:12.862.301   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
108 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:12.862.303   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
109 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  3   00:12.862.304   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
110 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:12.862.305   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
111 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  4   00:12.862.370   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
112 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:12.862.371   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
113 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  5   00:12.862.373   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController visibleViewController]
114 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:12.862.374   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController visibleViewController]
115 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  6   00:12.862.376   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController visibleViewController]
116 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:12.862.377   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController visibleViewController]
117 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  7   00:12.862.774   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
118 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:12.862.776   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
119 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 6   00:12.877.586   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
120 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 5   00:12.877.604   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
121 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 4   00:12.877.604   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
122 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 3   00:12.877.605   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
123 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 2   00:12.877.610   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
124 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 1   00:12.877.611   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
125 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Retain  2   00:13.292.620   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
126 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Autorelease <null>  00:13.292.621   0   UIKit   -[UINavigationController topViewController]
127 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 1   00:13.292.700   0   UIKit   -[UIViewController dealloc]
128 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Release 0   00:13.292.853   0   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal
129 0x14532980  MyPopUpViewController   Zombie  -1  00:13.439.920   0   UIKit   -[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedForComponent:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could the zombie be some object you manage inside of `MyPopUpViewController`? I notice that the zombie error message refers to `[UIPickerView _sendSelectionChangedForComponent:]`. I wonder what does this have to do with the controller?

One possibility is that the `UIPicker` is trying to send a message to its delegate (I suppose, your controller) *after* the modal is dismissed. One way to fix this would be setting the `UIPicker` `delegate` property to `nil` in the `release` method of your controller. Please, give this a try; I hope it helps....

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yes, the modal view presents a picker - would the zombie diagnostic report the higher object?

Comment: Thank you for your additional edit regarding the call to the delegate, I'd been scrutinising the code following your first comment and had reached the same conclusion, and the same proposed fix, and testing is currently underway - this was always a tricky bug to provoke, but I haven't seen the problem since this fix. I think that's quite subtle, but fits the evidence (timing differences on simulator vs. iPhone etc).  Thank you for your help.